# QML Coverflow very slow

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to implement a CoverFlow for a non touch application. Something like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MT58xIzp5c

I got the basics working but have two problems:

1. using the mouse wheel is extremely slow in comparison to flicking, especially if I scroll very fast. How can I get the `incrementCurrentIndex()` and `decrementCurrentIndex()` functions to be as fast as flicking?
2. When scrolling from one item to the next, I can see the white background for a second (the items don't move at the same time). Is there maybe a way to fix this?

Here is a working example of my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800
    MouseArea {
        //the mouse events will be replaced with c++ events later
        anchors.fill: parent
        onWheel: {
            if (wheel.angleDelta.y < 0)
            {
                view.incrementCurrentIndex()
            }
            else if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0)
            {
                view.decrementCurrentIndex()
            }
        }
    }

    PathView {
        id: view
        property int itemAngle: 40.0
        property int itemSize: width/3.5

        anchors.fill: parent
        pathItemCount: 10
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
        preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5
        interactive: true
        model: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
        delegate: viewDelegate
        path: Path {
            startX: 0
            startY: height / 2
            PathPercent { value: 0.0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: view.itemAngle }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: 0 }


            PathLine {x: view.width*0.4; y: view.height / 2}
            PathPercent { value: 0.48 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: view.itemAngle }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 10 }


            PathLine { relativeX: 0; relativeY: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: 0.0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 10 }


            PathLine {x: view.width*0.6; y: view.height / 2}
            PathPercent { value: 0.52 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: 0.0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 10 }


            PathLine { relativeX: 0; relativeY: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: -view.itemAngle }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: view.itemSize }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 10 }


            PathLine {x: view.width; y: view.height / 2}
            PathPercent { value: 1 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: -view.itemAngle }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: view.itemSize }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 0 }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: viewDelegate
        Rectangle {
            id: flipItem
            width: view.itemSize
            height: view.height
            color: "white"
            z: PathView.z

            property var rotationAngle: PathView.angle
            property var rotationOrigin: PathView.origin

            transform:
                Rotation {
                id: rot
                axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 }
                angle: rotationAngle
                origin.x: rotationOrigin
                origin.y: width
            }


            Rectangle {
                border.color: "black"
                border.width: 2
                color: (index%2 === 0) ? "yellow" : "royalblue"
                anchors.top: flipItem.top
                anchors.topMargin: 100
                anchors.left: flipItem.left
                anchors.right: flipItem.right
                width: flipItem.width
                height: flipItem.height*0.55
                smooth: true
                antialiasing: true
                Text {
                    text: model.modelData
                    color: "gray"
                    font.pixelSize: 30
                    font.bold: true
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve, is to control the scrolling from the c++ side (using events) and for it to be as fast as flicking with the mouse is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code and (I hope) working as you expect:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800
    MouseArea {
        //the mouse events will be replaced with c++ events later
        anchors.fill: parent
        onWheel: {
            if (wheel.angleDelta.y < 0)
            {
                if (scrollViewAnimation.running) {
                    scrollViewAnimation.stop()
                    scrollViewAnimation.to--
                    scrollViewAnimation.start()
                }
                else {
                    scrollViewAnimation.to = Math.round(view.offset - 1)
                    scrollViewAnimation.start()
                }
            }
            else if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0)
            {
                if (scrollViewAnimation.running) {
                    scrollViewAnimation.stop()
                    scrollViewAnimation.to++
                    scrollViewAnimation.start()
                }
                else {
                    scrollViewAnimation.to = Math.round(view.offset + 1)
                    scrollViewAnimation.start()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PathView {
        id: view
        property int itemAngle: 40.0
        property int itemSize: width/3.5

        anchors.fill: parent
        pathItemCount: 10
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
        preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5
        interactive: true
        model: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
        delegate: viewDelegate

        onDragStarted: {
            scrollViewAnimation.stop()
        }

        NumberAnimation on offset {
            id: scrollViewAnimation
            duration: 250
            easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
        }

        path: Path {
            startX: 0
            startY: height / 2
            PathPercent { value: 0.0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: view.itemAngle }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: 0 }


            PathLine {x: view.width*0.4; y: view.height / 2}
            PathPercent { value: 0.45 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: view.itemAngle }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 10 }


            PathLine { relativeX: 0; relativeY: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: 0.0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 10 }


            PathLine {x: view.width*0.6; y: view.height / 2}
            PathPercent { value: 0.55 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: 0.0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 10 }


            PathLine { relativeX: 0; relativeY: 0 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: -view.itemAngle }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: view.itemSize }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 10 }


            PathLine {x: view.width; y: view.height / 2}
            PathPercent { value: 1 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: -view.itemAngle }
            PathAttribute { name: "origin"; value: view.itemSize }
            PathAttribute { name: "z"; value: 0 }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: viewDelegate
        Rectangle {
            id: flipItem
            width: view.itemSize
            height: view.height
            color: "white"
            z: PathView.z

            property var rotationAngle: PathView.angle
            property var rotationOrigin: PathView.origin

            transform:
                Rotation {
                id: rot
                axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 }
                angle: rotationAngle
                origin.x: rotationOrigin
                origin.y: width
            }


            Rectangle {
                border.color: "black"
                border.width: 2
                color: (index%2 === 0) ? "yellow" : "royalblue"
                anchors.top: flipItem.top
                anchors.topMargin: 100
                anchors.left: flipItem.left
                anchors.right: flipItem.right
                width: flipItem.width
                height: flipItem.height*0.55
                smooth: true
                antialiasing: true
                Text {
                    text: model.modelData
                    color: "gray"
                    font.pixelSize: 30
                    font.bold: true
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. The problem with scrolling was that functions `PathView.incrementCurrentIndex()` and `PathView.decrementCurrentIndex()` move the `PathView` only to the next element. For example you are on index 1, call `PathView.incrementCurrentIndex()` 4 times quickly and the result is you move just to index 2 instead of 5. I made an `Animation` that moves the `PathView` (not sure if it is moving in the right direction though). Also please note `onDragStarted: { scrollViewAnimation.stop() }`.
2. To get rid of white space while scrolling I just modified `PathPercent { value: 0.48 }` and `PathPercent { value: 0.52 }` to `PathPercent { value: 0.45 }` and `PathPercent { value: 0.55 }`